# Ranking with Spotfire

Tags: python, spotfire

I am looking for some help, apologies I am a beginner in Spotfire and trying unsuccessfuly to solve my issue

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCpU6.png)

On the pic above, I would like to know how can I get this ranking. I have a "Production" column where for the same Rowkey, I have in the production column the same information registred several times. However for further calculus, I need it only once. So I'm looking for a way to rank it like in the table above.

I've tried the following expression but that's not working :

```
DenseRank([Production],"ASC",[Rowkey],"ties.method=first")
DenseRank([Production],"ASC",[Rowkey])
```

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow"). In order for us to help you, it is necessary that you show your effort and submit data to be used to reproduce your problem. While providing an image is helpful, it doesn't allow for reproducing the issue. Please edit your question to show a minimal reproducible set.  See [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") for details.

Comment: I don't understand what the desired outcome is. From your table it looks like for each value of Production you put a 1 against the highest value of PaperStock and a 0 against the others (not sure here, as there are only two). Can you elaborate on what the rules should be and/or give a larger sample? I don't see the same information registered multiple times as the values of PaperStock vary